# how to collect multiple values as a single string in postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I have tables :

```
Project table

id name
-------
1  A
2  B

Assignment table

id name project_id
-------------------
1  A1   1
2  A2   1
3  A3   2
```

I wish to write a query that returns each project with the name of the assignments created from it, like :

```
project_id  assignments
-----------------------
1            A1,A2
2            A3
```

Is there any way to achieve that ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can join the tables and use `array_agg` to combine the values separated by a comma

```
SELECT a.id, array_agg(b.name) assignments
FROM    Project a
        INNER JOIN assignment b
          ON a.id = b.project_ID
GROUP BY a.id
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/df056/3)

or by using `STRING_AGG`

```
SELECT a.id, STRING_AGG(b.name, ', ' ORDER BY b.name) assignments
FROM    Project a
        INNER JOIN assignment b
          ON a.id = b.project_ID
GROUP BY a.id
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/df056/5)

Comment: With 9.1 `string_agg()` might be more approriate.