# GROUP BY but get all values from other column

Tags: sql, group-by

I''ll explain what I need to do on example. First of all, we have a simple table like this one, named *table*:

```
id | name
===+=====
1  | foo
1  | bar
1  | foobar
2  | foo
2  | bar
2  | foobar
```

Now the query:

```
SELECT t.* FROM table t GROUP BY t.id
```

Will get us result similar to this one:

```
id | name
===+=====
1  | foo
2  | foo
```

But is it possible, to collect all values of *name* to have result like this?

```
id | name
===+=================
1  | foo, bar, foobar
2  | foo, bar, foobar
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? MySQL, SQL Server?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, astander: DBMS doesn't really matter, let's say MySQL and PG.

Comment: The DBMS **does** matter. The solutions will be different.

Comment: And for Oracle one would use `LISTAGG()`, I guess.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Using MySQL you can use [GROUP_CONCAT(expr)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

> This function returns a string result with the concatenated non-NULL
>   values from a group. It returns NULL if there are no non-NULL values.
>   The full syntax is as follows:

```
GROUP_CONCAT([DISTINCT] expr [,expr ...]
             [ORDER BY {unsigned_integer | col_name | expr}
                 [ASC | DESC] [,col_name ...]]
             [SEPARATOR str_val])
```

Something like

```
SELECT ID, GROUP_CONCAT(name) GroupedName
FROM Table1
GROUP BY ID
```

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/afbca/2)

Comment: I found that with this approach, the GroupedName value is truncated to 1024 characters.  Is there a way to get around this?   (this was in MySql 8.0.3)

Comment: Actually I discovered it's determined by the `group_concat_max_len` config variable as described here

Answer (score 25):

For SQL Server (**before** 2017) use [`FOR XML`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/for-xml-sql-server) clause and [`STUFF()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/stuff-transact-sql) function for that:

```
SELECT distinct id, name = 
    STUFF((SELECT ' , ' + name
           FROM Table1 b 
           WHERE b.id = a.id 
          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
FROM Table1 a
GROUP BY id;
```

#### UPDATE

With SQL Server 2017, you can simply use [`STRING_AGG()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql) function to achieve that:

```
SELECT ID, STRING_AGG (name, ', ') AS Name
FROM Table1
GROUP BY ID
```

#### See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/bee79/1)

Answer (score 24):

For Postgres use [`string_agg()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html)

```
select id, 
       string_agg(name, ',' order by name) as name_list
from the_table
group by id
order by id;
```

Comment: You cane use `array_agg` if you want to have an array instead of a string. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/13025857/888294

Answer (score 1):

Below query works for you if you are using db2:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id, LISTAGG(names, ',')
FROM tb
GROUP BY id;
```