# How to send email to selected email in php

Tags: php, email

[image: table what i fetched from database]

```
while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) 
{
    $email_message .= '<tr>';
    $id= $row2['id'];
    $value= $row2['format( a.total_value, 2 )'];
    $email= $row2['email'];
    $email_message .='<td>'."$id".'</td>';
    $email_message .='<td>'."$value".'</td>';
    $email_message .='<td>'."$email".'</td>';
    $email_message .= '</tr>';
}
```

i want to send email to xx@gmail.com(id=4) with first five row  info and send email to ss@yy.com(id=13) with last row info..
                After fetching above table from db how to do code for above using php. please help me out.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/fr/function.mail.php

Comment: I know mail function but how to select first five row values from the fetched table

Comment: ... so your question shoud have been regarding `SQL`? `SELECT email FROM wtf LIMIT 5` shoul work on some *DB* ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try something like that :

```
$clients = array();

while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) 
{
    if (!array_key_exists($row2['email'], $clients)) {
        $clients[$row2['email']] = array($row2['format( a.total_value, 2 )']);
    }
    else {
        $clients[$row2['email']][] = $row2['format( a.total_value, 2 )'];
    }
}

foreach ($clients as $email => $values) {
    $email_message .= '<tr>';
    $id= $row2['id'];

    $email_message .='<td>'."$id".'</td>';

    foreach ($values as $value) {
        $email_message .='<td>'."$value".'</td>';
    }

    $email_message .='<td>'."$email".'</td>';
    $email_message .= '</tr>';
}
```

Comment: not only first five rows for all six rows. first five rows info have to send an email to xx@gmail.com and last row info email to ss@yy.com

Comment: OK. I guess you'll have to parse the data first, and store it in some array, containing your email adresses and the info to be sent. If the address already is in the array, just add the info. Then, parse this array and send the email. If you want a complete example tell me, but it shouldn't be hard to code.

Comment: Can u pls provide an relavent example

Comment: the above displaying table is a result of my mysql query

Comment: I edited my answer, please tell me if this is any help.

Comment: What is $mysql_results?? giving error for that like undefined variable

Comment: Sorry, it was a test variable. Answer edited, should work right now.

Comment: id value
 6,349.00 ramya@igoorganic.in 2,250.00 ramya@igoorganic.in 300.00 ramya@igoorganic.in 1,000.00 ramya@igoorganic.in 1,000.00 ramya@igoorganic.in

Comment: am getting like above in email.. its corrct but id not displaying.. and table alignment also not coming properly. coming next to each other

Comment: table formatting done but nw only pblm is not disaplying id in email message

Comment: You have to store the ID on the $clients array as well.

Comment: The easiest way though would be to get the results straight from MySQL. Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18910134/group-by-but-get-all-values-from-other-column

Comment: if i store ID in $client means $value returning ID and format( a.total_value, 2 ) in same cell, its not coming in seperate cells

Answer (score 0):

You can use default mail() function. Find the example below.

```
<?php
// The message
$message = "Line 1\r\nLine 2\r\nLine 3";

// In case any of our lines are larger than 70 characters, we should use wordwrap()
$message = wordwrap($message, 70, "\r\n");

// Send
mail('caffeinated@example.com', 'My Subject', $message);
?>
```

Note: If you are using this on ur localhost, you need to check and change your smtp setting in php.in file. Mail function may/may-not work at all the time depending on your smtp settings.