# SQL Query to Concatenate text

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to find the best way to consolidate the string in the fields that have the same value. Please look at the example below:

Table1:

```
Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | Column4
test1     test2     test3     string1
test1     test2     test3     string2
test4     test5     test6     string3
test4     test5     test6     string4
```

The result need to be inserted to Table2 like following:

Table2:

```
Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | Column4
test1     test2     test3     string1 string2
test4     test5     test6     string3 string4
```

I need to avoid Cursors please. Thank you.
Please note: I can not use the XML PATH.

The following query wouldn't work:

```
SELECT
      m.Column1,m.Column2,m.Column3
    , Column4 = STUFF((
          SELECT ' ' + Column4
          FROM dbo.Table1
          FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 1, '')
FROM dbo.Table1 m
```

Comment: Do you have only two rows that match?

Comment: Investigate "group by" on the first three columns, and the use of STUFF... check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13647394/concatenate-one-field-after-group-by

Comment: just another similar answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18910134/group-by-but-get-all-values-from-other-column

Comment: Similar @morsik but for SQL Server they'll need this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591490/how-to-make-a-query-with-group-concat-in-sql-server which is mentioned in your post but as the third answer. MySQL was accepted.

Comment: @gordonLinoff no it can be up to 4 rows at the time that match.

Comment: And the list of dupes can get even bigger...

Comment: @pmbAustin  can you please provide an example?

Comment: I've listed 4 different duplicates. Surly you can find your answer in at least one of them...

Comment: Thank you. But I cant use XML Path since the data sometimes includes characters that can not be serialized.

Comment: @zoharpeled shall I ask the question again?

Comment: Have you tried `(select .... for xml path, type).value('.', 'varchar(max)')`?

Comment: Yes, still the same error.

Comment: If you could edit the question to include an example that you can't use `for xml` with, then I (or someone else) will probably re-open it.

Comment: done. Please re-open the question.

Comment: Show some sample data that failed...