# Client side GroupBy is not supported

Tags: c#, linq, group-by, entity-framework-core-3.0

I have the following Entity Framework Core 3.0 query:

```
var units = await context.Units
  .SelectMany(y => y.UnitsI18N)
  .OrderBy(y => y.Name)
  .GroupBy(y => y.LanguageCode)
  .ToDictionaryAsync(y => y.Key, y => y.Select(z => z.Name));
```

I get the following error:

```
Client side GroupBy is not supported.
```

To run the query on the client, or part of it, I would do the following:

```
var units = context.Units
  .SelectMany(y => y.UnitsI18N)
  .OrderBy(y => y.Name)
  .AsEnumerable()
  .GroupBy(y => y.LanguageCode)
  .ToDictionary(y => y.Key, y => y.Select(z => z.Name));
```

Now it works.

Why am I getting this error if I am not running the query on the client?

Comment: GroupBy is messed up I guess. Even if you write only GroupBy in the query, it gives you the same error. My only solution also was to use AsEnumerable() before GroupBy()

Comment: I have the same problem and downgraded to dotnetcore 2.2 and .NetStandard 2.0 to keep working. It's not logical to block a working feature. OK, it penalises performance, but I know and I need it.

Comment: @VanoMaisuradze I think in EF Core 3.0 is always necessary to use a function like MAX, AVG, ... before GroupBy. I am trying to figure out what is the best way to solve this ... Usually in SQL if you SELECT the column that is used in the GroupBy then it works ...

Comment: @Duefectu Using NET Core 2.2 or using NET Core 3.0 with .AsEnumerable() is the same ... Both run on the client. So no need to downgrade to 2.2. Just use .AsEnumerable(). My question is how to not use .AsEnumerable() in my query so it runs everything on the server.

Comment: Apart of your question, the problem is how to port a big project to dotnetcore 3.0 without to change the half of my linq queries?

Comment: the only workaround seems to be so far by using `.AsEnumerable()` or `.ToList()` before `GroupBy` to bypass the ef core query translator's bugs. You can use `Where` clause first to fetch as minimum data as possible

Comment: If you find bugs or have implementation questions regarding EF 3, please first check [here](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/) if it's a known issue. We can't handle all these things at Stack Overflow. Usually, there's nothing we can do about it. Nor can we explain implementation decisions.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Your `.GroupBy(y => y.LanguageCode).ToDictionaryAsync(y => y.Key, y => y.Select(z => z.Name));` cannot be converted to SQL.
EF Core 3.0 will throw exception to make sure you know that all records in `Units` will be fetched from database before grouping and map to Dictionary.

It's top breaking change in EF Core 3.0.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes

Comment: Your answer is good, but from EF Core seriously? My table has millions of entries, I'm not going to load them first on the client. No workaround ?

Comment: **Workaround:** I created a View with grouped data and Create new Entity and in EF 3 you can use **modelBuilder.Entity<Transaction>.ToView("VM_Transactions");**

Comment: What if we try to use a ToList on the IQueryable and then a GroupBy?

Comment: or better... the linq query must be correctly filtered with right and good where conditions... then when can do a ToList and in the end we can GroupBy as alternative I think to query a sql view

Comment: @jsgoupil This means that the underlying database provider could not execute your query on the database side. Before EF 3 this would have only generate a warning and your query would have been executed in your client-side by using LINQ-to-Objects. Starting in EF 3, they throw an exception to ensure that you are aware that the database provider wasn't able to execute the query in the database side. Please refer to [EF Core version 3 breaking changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#linq-queries-are-no-longer-evaluated-on-the-client).

Comment: @jsgoupil Based on the sample code above, pulling every single record into client memory is exactly what that code is doing. See the answer provided by Jan below highlighting how dictionarys store data.

Answer (score 223):

It seems like there is a common misconception about what LINQ `GroupBy` does and what SQL `GROUP BY` is able to do. Since I fell into the exact same trap and had to wrap my head around this recently, I decided to write a more thorough explanation of this issue.

---

**Short answer:**

The LINQ `GroupBy` is **much different** from the SQL `GROUP BY` statement: LINQ just **divides** the underlying collection into chunks depending on a key, while SQL additionally **applies an aggregation function** to condense each of these chunks down into a *single value*.

This is why EF has to perform your LINQ-kind `GroupBy` in memory.

Before EF Core 3.0, this was done *implicitly*, so EF downloaded all result rows and then applied the LINQ `GroupBy`. However, this implicit behavior might let the programmer expect that the *entire* LINQ query is executed in SQL, with potentially enormous performance impact when the result set is rather large. For this reason, implicit client side evaluation of `GroupBy` was [disabled completely in EF Core 3.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#linq-queries-are-no-longer-evaluated-on-the-client).

Now it is required to explicitly call functions like `.AsEnumerable()` or `.ToList()`, which download the result set and continue with in-memory LINQ operations.

---

**Long answer:**

The following table `solvedExercises` will be the running example for this answer:

```
+-----------+------------+
| StudentId | ExerciseId |
+-----------+------------+
|         1 |          1 |
|         1 |          2 |
|         2 |          2 |
|         3 |          1 |
|         3 |          2 |
|         3 |          3 |
+-----------+------------+
```

A record `X | Y` in this table denotes that student `X` has solved exercise `Y`.

In the question, a common use case of LINQ's `GroupBy` method is described: Take a collection and group it into chunks, where the rows in each chunk share a common key.

In our example, we might want to get a `Dictionary<int, List<int>>`, which contains a list of solved exercises for each student. With LINQ, this is very straightforward:

```
var result = solvedExercises
    .GroupBy(e => e.StudentId)
    .ToDictionary(e => e.Key, e => e.Select(e2 => e2.ExerciseId).ToList());
```

Output (for full code see [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jMZz20)):

```
Student #1: 1 2 
Student #2: 2 
Student #3: 1 2 3
```

This is easy to represent with C# datatypes, since we can nest `List` and `Dictionary` as deep as we like to.

Now we try to imagine this as an SQL query result. SQL query results are usually represented as a table, where we can freely choose the returned columns. To represent our above query as SQL query result, we would need to

- generate multiple result tables,
- put the grouped rows into an array or
- somehow insert a "result set separator".

As far as I know, none of these approaches is implemented in practice. At most, there are some hacky work-arounds like MySQL's [`GROUP_CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat), which allows to combine the result rows into a string ([relevant SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18910206/8528014)).

Thus we see, that SQL **cannot** yield results that match LINQ's notion of `GroupBy`.

Instead, SQL only allows so-called *aggregation*: If we, for example, wanted to count how many exercises have been passed by a student, we would write

```sql
SELECT StudentId,COUNT(ExerciseId)
FROM solvedExercises
GROUP BY StudentId
```

...which will yield

```
+-----------+-------------------+
| StudentId | COUNT(ExerciseId) |
+-----------+-------------------+
|         1 |                 2 |
|         2 |                 1 |
|         3 |                 3 |
+-----------+-------------------+
```

Aggregation functions reduce a set of rows into a single value, usually a scalar. Examples are row count, sum, maximum value, minimum value, and average.

This *is* implemented by EF Core: Executing

```
var result = solvedExercises
    .GroupBy(e => e.StudentId)
    .Select(e => new { e.Key, Count = e.Count() })
    .ToDictionary(e => e.Key, e => e.Count);
```

generates the above SQL. Note the `Select`, which tells EF which *aggregation function* it should use for the generated SQL query.

---

In summary, the LINQ `GroupBy` function is much more general than the SQL `GROUP BY` statement, which due to SQL's restrictions only allows to return a single, two dimensional result table. Thus, queries like the one in the question and the first example in this answer have to be evaluated in memory, after downloading the SQL result set.

Instead of *implicitly* doing this, in EF Core 3.0 the developers [chose to throw an exception in this case](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#linq-queries-are-no-longer-evaluated-on-the-client); this prevents accidental downloading of an entire, potentially large table with millions of rows, which might get unnoticed during development due to a small test database.

Comment: At first I thought it was weird that they changed it, but from your description it makes me wonder if my previously 'working' queries were then actually performed client-side. Great explanation.

Comment: I agree with the above, but a good solution is missing.

Comment: Guaranteed that 9 out of every 10 devs DID NOT know the low-level details like this post has prior to coming across problems (most likely due to a .NET Core version upgrade that's > 2.1). Very "deceptive" on MS's  part to not put this disclaimer in CAPITAL RED text within their documentation. Instead, they throw an exception smh

Comment: Wow, now that is subtle. Adding a `Select()` to make EF Core realize it can and should do this server-side after all and translate that into `GROUP BY` SQL (I can add here that an additional LINQ `Where()` afterwards will correctly generate a `GROUP BY ... HAVING` syntax.

But these are the instances where I feel like an abstract ORM has its disadvantages. It would make far more sense to me to not re-use the LINQ `GroupBy` method in this case and have the ORM second guess if you want to do something on the client or server. They are two completely different things.

Answer (score -1):

One possible solution (works for me) is to make the `GroupBy` on a `List` object.

```
var units = (
  await context.Units
  .SelectMany(y => y.UnitsI18N)
  .GroupBy(y => y.LanguageCode)
  .ToDictionaryAsync(y => y.Key, y => y.Select(z => z.Name))
  ).ToList().OrderBy(y => y.Name);
```

Comment: This answer has the GroupBy still being performed on the query.

Answer (score -2):

The linq GroupBy method can do things that a database query cannot. This is why linq is throwing the exception. It's not a missing feature, but in older versions of linq, it simply enumerated the entire table and then ran the GroupBy locally.

Linq query syntax happens to have a `group` keyword that can be translated to a database query.

Here's a mostly working example of how to run your query on the database using query syntax:

```cs
var kvPairs = from y in context.Units
              from u in y.UnitsI18N
              orderby u.Name
              group u by u.LanguageCode into g
              select new KeyValuePair<string,IEnumerable<string>>(g.Key, g.Select(z => z.Name));

return new Dictionary<string,IEnumerable<string>>>(kvPairs);
```

See this article from Microsoft for more information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/complex-query-operators#groupby

Comment: Perhaps someone wants to clue me in on why this answer is so incredibly wrong?

Comment: I don't think that this `group u by ...` will be translated into a SQL `GROUP BY` statement, since you don't do any aggregation (which is required by `GROUP BY`). However, I may be wrong - did you run this query on a database with EF Core 3? Could you also show the generated SQL? Unfortunately I don't have a corresponding test setup right now.

Comment: Just thinking...actually, for the given simple example, it does not really matter whether this is executed on the server or in memory - the entire result set is being downloaded anyway. But I wonder whether LINQ/EF are able to detect this. As a side note, I always assumed that, during compilation, the query syntax is being translated into the extension method syntax - thus yielding the same query as in the question.

Comment: Alright, I just tested a simplified version of the proposed query, and it does result in an `InvalidOperationException`.

Comment: Thank you @JanWichelmann for your analysis. I guessed a bit at how to translate your original query, and it looks like I missed the fact that there needs to be an aggregate function applied to the group values. That makes perfect sense since that is a requirement of SQL.

I found this question while trying to solve my own issue, but in my case I was using an aggregate function. And due to the restrictive nature of query syntax, I had to re-structure my query when I converted it, resulting in something that could be executed on the database.

Answer (score -2):

```
var test = unitOfWork.PostCategory.GetAll().Include(u=>u.category).GroupBy(g => g.category.name).Select(s => new
                {

                    name = s.Key,
                    count = s.Count()

                }).OrderBy(o=>o.count).ToList();
```

you can try this code part...  it will works.. I have tried

Answer (score -2):

**Client-Side Group-By is Supported**

*Tested with EF Core 3.1.15.0*

The following code returns the `Client side GroupBy is not supported.` error:

```
MyEntity
    .GroupBy(x => x.MyProperty)
    .ToDictionaryAsync(x => x.Key, x => x.Count())
    .Dump();
```

But for some reason, you can add a `.Select()` after the `.GroupBy()`, and it compiles and runs the expected SQL:

```
MyEntity
    .GroupBy(x => x.MyProperty)
    .Select(g => new { Key = g.Key, Count = g.Count() })
    .ToDictionaryAsync(x => x.Key, x => x.Count)
    .Dump();
```

Compiles to:

```
SELECT [t].[MyProperty] AS [Key], COUNT(*) AS [Count]
FROM [dbo].[MyEntity] AS [t]
GROUP BY [t].[MyProperty]
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11564436/14565661