# Grouping by a boolean property does not work in EF Core

Tags: entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

I have the following data model:

```
public class JobPost
{
    public in PostId {get;set;}
    public bool IsRemote {get;set}
}
```

I'm trying to group the posts by a bool property which doesn't seem to work.

```
 from p in posts
 group p by new
            {
                IsRemote =  p.IsRemote 
            } into grp
 select new PostViewModel
            {
               IsRemote = grp.Key.IsRemote
            };
```

Could someone please tell me how to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Clarify "does not work". e.g. Are you getting exception? If yes, what? etc.

Comment: @Ivan Stoev grouping by a bool column

Comment: the posted code gives you result not grouped? or an exception? which ef core version you use?

Comment: @Sajid yes it throws an excpetion, I', using version 2.2.3

Comment: And that doesn't group by a bool.  It groups by an anonymous type containing a single read-only property of type bool.

Comment: @arif there is a problem with group by for EF core. but note for 2.1 i think, try to execute the query with and without [.AsEnumerable()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatableextensions.asenumerable?view=netcore-3.1) : ``var result = from job in posts.AsEnumerable()
                         group job by job.IsRemote into groupedJobs
                         select new { groupedJobs.Key };`` and check the result.

Comment: @David Brown, thanks for your answer. Which versions does support this? I upgraded to the latest but it complained on my owned types...

Comment: @Sajid I don't think AsNumerable() will do because it will execute my database query before grouping..

Comment: i think group by work just for <= 2.1 version. for >= 2.2 it's not translated to sql ``AsEnumerable`` just for checking if your code works fine. the same problem for 3.0 version here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58138556/client-side-groupby-is-not-supported. try to use ``ToTraceString`` to check the query.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class JobPost
{
    public int PostId {get;set;}
    public bool? IsRemote {get;set}
}
```

I dont know if this qualifies as a solution but changing my property type from bool to a nullable bool helped.

Comment: It's nullable in database?

Comment: If the value is null,it's grouped too?