# Using GroupBy in LINQ to get last inserted rows

Tags: c#, sqlite, linq, ef-core-3.1

I have a simple table that I would like to get the last inserted rows from using GroupBy.

I have the following code that works without grouping but would like to make a new function with grouping

```
 public Session FindLastFinished(IdentityUser user)
    {
        return _dbContext.Sessions.OrderByDescending(o => o.CreatedAt).FirstOrDefault(s => s.User.Equals(user) && s.Progress.Equals(Status.Finished.ToString()));
    }
```

I need to add a grouping for the column ScenarioId so that it will return the last inserted row for each ScenarioId but am having trouble adding the GroupBy syntax.

```
public List<Session> FindLastFinishedByScenarios(IdentityUser user)
```

Comment: Don't you have `Scenario` entity with collection navigation property similar to  `public ICollection<Session> Sessions { get; set; }` ?

Comment: public DbSet<Session> Sessions { get; set; }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
_dbContext.Sessions.GroupBy(s => s.ScenarioId)
.ToDictionary(e => e.Key, e => e.OrderByDescending(o => o.CreatedAt).First())
```

In that case you will have a dictionary that have the scenario id as a key and the last inserted item as value.

Comment: I get the following error : Client side GroupBy is not supported.

Comment: Are you using EF Core ? Which version ?

Comment: Yes EF Core, Net Core 3.1

Comment: It seems is not always usable anymore. You can use a ".AsEnumerable()" after the "Sessions" but it means all records will be fetch from the database before applying the group by which is not great (but it seems in the past that's how EF dealt with group by) : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58138556/client-side-groupby-is-not-supported.

Comment: So my answer will not help you (unless you use the .AsEnumerable() or a .ToList(), you will get the result you want but in an inefficient way).

Comment: Efficiency is not a big deal here....this is a proof of concept application with limited users and probably only a few thousand records in the table by the end of the test.

Comment: It should be OK then :-)

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
_dbContext.Sessions.ToList()
.GroupBy(x => x.ScenarioId)
.Select(groupOrderedByCreatedAt =>
       {
            var orderedGroup = groupOrderedByCreatedAt.OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedAt);
                //Work with the orderedGroup
        });
```

Works like this:

1. You group them by scenarioId
2. Select on it takes each group
3. You order each group by createdAt

Then you work with the ordered group

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0411 The type arguments for method 'Enumerable.Select<TSource, TResult>(IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource, int, TResult>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly. 

It doesn't like the "select" part of the statement and won't compile.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this to solve it for now since efficiency isn't the biggest issue.

```
_dbContext.Sessions.ToList().GroupBy(s => s.ScenarioId).ToList().
                Select(e => e.OrderByDescending(o => o.CreatedAt).First())
.Where(w => w.User.Equals(user) && w.Progress.Equals(Status.Finished.ToString())).ToList();
```

If anyone has a better idea I am all ears!