# EF Core nested group by - Client side GroupBy is not supported

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have this LINQ which the first foreach loop is to print unique file extension and the inner foreach loop is to print all the file of that file extension.

But it breaks at the first foreach loop with error

> Client side GroupBy is not supported.

```
var fileByFileExtension = _context.FileDocuments.GroupBy(file => file.FileExtension);

foreach (var fileExt in fileByFileExtension)
{
    WriteLine(fileExt.Key);
    foreach (var item in fileExt)
    {
        WriteLine(" " + item.FileName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try
var fileByFileExtension = _context.FileDocuments.ToList().GroupBy(file => file.FileExtension);

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Client side GroupBy is not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58138556/client-side-groupby-is-not-supported)