# Client side GroupBy is not supported - fix

Tags: c#, sqlite, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

How to fix this query to meet the new .NET Core 3 update?

```
   var rtn =
            from fav in _context.AdvertFavorite
            join advert in _context.Adverts on fav.AdvertID equals advert.AdvertID
            join blob in _context.Blobs on advert.AdvertID equals blob.AdvertID
            join user in _userManager.Users on advert.UserID equals user.Id
            where fav.UserID == usrid
            group new { blob, user, advert } by new { advert.AdvertID } into grp
            select grp;

        var rtn1 = rtn.ToList();

        return rtn1;
```

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58138556/client-side-groupby-is-not-supported)

Comment: Not really. However, I have updated the code snippet. I'd like someone to say how I can rewrite it in LINQ query, the other one is not LINQ

Comment: That is LINQ, query syntax vs fluent though

Comment: @PeterKapenaPeter can you explain how it's different? Is the exception you're getting not coming from Entity Framework? As gilliduck says, both are LINQ it's just different syntax.

Comment: If your previous version was LINQ fluent/lambda syntax, you were probably better off, as EF Core won't do server side grouping, you need to flatten and do client side grouping by putting in an `AsEnumerable` just before calling `GroupBy`. PS EF Core doesn't do it because SQL doesn't have a group concept either.

Comment: I managed to just rewrite my code because even client side group was not grouping at all, [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58138556/client-side-groupby-is-not-supported).

Comment: ` var list = new List<dynamic>();
            var rtn =(from fav in _context.AdvertFavorite
                 join advert in _context.Adverts on fav.AdvertID equals advert.AdvertID
                 join user in _userManager.Users on advert.UserID equals user.Id
                 where fav.UserID == usrid       select new { user, advert }).ToList();
            rtn.ForEach((r) =>
            {                var blob = _context.Blobs.Where(b => b.AdvertID == r.advert.AdvertID).FirstOrDefault();                list.Add(new { blob, r.user, r.advert, });            });            return list;`