# .net Core EF Trying to make gruop by query

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

Hi I got data in datatable like this

```
Aid Bid Atext Aword  CrDate
1    1   hi    h      now
1    1   hii   hi     now
1    2   k     k      now
2    1   kk    k      now
2    3   kkk   k      now
```

Aid with Bid, A and B is different entity. I want to group by the other colums
My try is

```
var groups= _context.VmAuthBooks.GroupBy(x=>x.Aid);
```

it gives error.

```
Client Side GroupBy is not supported.
```

I want to group them by Aid && Bid like

```
var groups= _context.VmAuthBooks.GroupBy(x=>x.Aid && x=>x.Bid);
```

Then get the Atext Aword CrDate
It will be like

```
Aid Bid
1   1 textcount
1   2 textcount
2   1 textcount
2   3 textcount
```

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicated https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58138556/client-side-groupby-is-not-supported

Comment: var result = solvedExercises
    .GroupBy(e => e.StudentId)
    .ToDictionary(e => e.Key, e => e.Select(e2 => e2.ExerciseId).ToList());  is good answer but I gotta make it by 2 id

Comment: To group by multi fileds, try this ` .GroupBy(x => new {Aid, Bid})
                .Select(e => new {e.Key, Count = e.Count()})
                .ToDictionary(e => e.Key, e => e.Count);`