# MySQL Grouping with value separations not working

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table that records item with item, make, model & serial number as follows :

### item table

| item_name | make | model | serial_no | qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Computer | HP | Pro 300D | 123ert34c10 | 1 |
| Computer | HP | Pro 400D | 123xgt34c110 | 1 |
| Printer | Canon | ir1210 | 56tyu78 | 1 |
| Computer | HP | Pro 400D | 123xgt34c111 | 1 |
| Printer | Canon | ir1215 | gh90fr | 1 |
| UPS | APC | A200 | apc5640400 | 1 |
| UPS | APC | A300 | apc5640401 | 1 |
| Computer | HP | Pro 300D | 123ert34c13 | 1 |

Then I need to group items by the item_name and make. And also needs to show all models & serial nos in the group summary as follows :

### Desired Output

| item_name | make | model | serial_no | qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Computer | HP | Pro 300D, Pro 400D | 123ert34c10, 123ert34c13, 123xgt34c110, 123xgt34c111 | 4 |
| Printer | Canon | ir1210, ir1215 | 56tyu78, gh90fr | 2 |
| UPS | APC | A200, A300 | apc5640400, apc5640401 | 2 |

I used the following simple query to do this.

```
SELECT item_name, make, model, serial_no, SUM(qty) AS qty FROM item GROUP BY item_name, make
```

But the query outs the following output without showing all models & serial nos under the relevant item_name & make.

### Incorrect Output

| item_name | make | model | serial_no | qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Computer | HP | Pro 300D | 123ert34c10 | 4 |
| Printer | Canon | ir1210 | 56tyu78 | 2 |
| UPS | APC | A200 | apc5640400 | 2 |

Some models & serial nos were missing. What may going wrong. Can anyone help ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GROUP BY but get all values from other column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18910134/group-by-but-get-all-values-from-other-column)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve the `Desired_Output` by using `GROUP_CONCAT()`. Here is the modified `sql`

```
SELECT
    item_name,
    make,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT model ORDER BY model) AS model,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT serial_no ORDER BY serial_no) AS serial_no,
    SUM(qty) AS qty
FROM item
GROUP BY item_name, make;
```

The `DISTINCT` ensures `model` and `serial_no` are included only once, while `GROUP_CONCAT` concatenates the results after they are sorted using `ORDER BY`

Answer (score 0):

When you `GROUP BY` you will get a single row for all the data grouped by given column but you will not get any summary or whatever of these data which is what you for some reason expected. This is actually correct for `GROUP BY`. If you want get all the details, you would need `GROUP_CONCAT()` function instead:

```sql
SELECT 
    item_name, 
    make, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT model ORDER BY model ASC) AS model,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT serial_no ORDER BY serial_no ASC) AS serial_no,
    SUM(qty) AS qty 
FROM 
    item
GROUP BY 
    item_name, 
    make;
```